# SQL Count issue

Tags: sql-server-2008

What the SQL is doing is counting all students who are seniors that have submitted an assessment with the assignment attached and the assessment is complete (no objective marked with an "I") for the 2013 Fall semester in each course.

I'm currently looking specifically at the ED495- Course. Basically what happened is the professor entered the assessment and added multiple files for the assignment (which each file name creates a record in the FileCabinet table) for a single student/assessment rather than just one file. So when it looks to see if there is a file that exists for that student it's seeing all of them and counting each one. There are only 5 students in that particular course. The output that I'm was expecting for that class should be 5 since each one did have a paper submitted with the assessment.

The "Count(*) Pool" is returning all possibles when I only need it to basically say yes there is at least one record for that student and count it.

```
      SELECT Course.CourseN, Course.Sect, COUNT(FileCabinet.TheFile) [Pool] 
        FROM Course 
  INNER JOIN RubricW ON Course.WID = RubricW.WID 
  INNER JOIN Students_CR ON Course.StuID = Students_CR.StuID 
  INNER JOIN FileCabinet ON Course.WID = FileCabinet.WID 
       WHERE Course.Year = 2013 
         AND Course.Semester = 'FA' 
         AND (Students_CR.CR = 'SR' AND Students_CR.Year = 2013 AND Students_CR.Sem = 'FA') 
         AND FileCabinet.TheFile IS NOT Null 
         AND (Obj1 NOT IN('I') OR Obj2 NOT IN('I') OR Obj3 NOT IN('I') OR Obj4 NOT IN('I') OR Obj5 NOT IN('I') OR Obj6 NOT IN('I') OR Obj7 NOT IN('I')) 
    GROUP BY Course.CourseN, Course.Sect
```

Result set:

```
CourseN Sect    Pool
AG232G  M1        7
AT481-  M1        9
CJ234-  M1        6
ED341-  M1        4
ED495-  M1       45
EN232-  M1        3
EN242-  M1        2
EN250G  M1        4
EN430G  M1        8
MK334-  M1        2
MK496-  M1        4
MT398-  M1       10
MU350G  M1        7
PS330-  M1        3
PS344-  M1        1
RP450-  M1        5
SY330-  M1        7
TH330G  M1        9
TH342G  M1        2
```

And the SQL is being used to assist the review board in pulling random assessments. There are multiple ways for them to pull and the list is to assist them on deciding on how many assessments they need to review.

Hope I explained it well enough. What I'm considering is restricting the professors from being able to submit multiple files from within my VB .NET code. I would like to prevent that if possible.

Comment: Hey, I haven't tried to wrap my head around the query yet, but on the off chance of a quick-fix: what happens if you `COUNT(DISTINCT Students_CR.StuID)`

Comment: That looks like the solution. I was thinking along that lines as the original I had COUNT(*) instead of COUNT(FileCabinet.TheFile). Now I just wonder why that was it. Thanks OGHaza.

Comment: :P You almost had it. I've posted it as an answer in case that fully solved it for you, if not comment again and I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
COUNT(DISTINCT Students_CR.StuID)
```

instead, that way each student will only be counted once regardless of how many files each has.